# Write-Host with a color depending on the value of the message

Tags: powershell

I would like to print a number in green if it's 100 or red if less, but this is not working

> Write-Host -ForegroundColor { (if ($number -eq 100) {Green} else
>   {Red}) } "$number"

How can I do this without having

> if (...) {Write-Host ...} else {Write-Host ...}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Write-Host $number -ForegroundColor $(if ($number -eq 100) {'Green'} else {'Red'})
```

You don't want to use `{}` in this case.  ForegroundColor does not accept a scriptblock and it is not pipeline bound.  Besides you're not piping anything into Write-Host.  A subexpression `$()` allows you to evaluate statements like if, foreach, etc.